# install Window 7 after Ubuntu 14

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, gparted

Can I install Window7 on an existing Ubuntu 14 laptop by shrinking the Ubuntu 14 partition, installing Windows 7 into the created freespace, and running Boot Repair to get the Grub boot menu with both Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.

Here is the layout of my partitions as shown by GParted:

```
Partition     FileSystem   Size           Flags
/dev/sda1   Fat32          512.00 Mig      boot 
/dev/sda2   ext4           224.42 Gig
/dev/sda3   linux-swap       7.97 Gig
```

Does this still look ok in terms of installing Windows after shrinking /dev/sda2?

Answer (score 1):

Not recommended, as Windows likes to delete everything already existing on the drive. You could try but you have to be very careful when installing to make sure it's the right partition

Comment: Yes, your comments proved dead on, especially when it comes to Windows 7. I had to start from scratch, reinstalling Win7, then using Win 7 partition manager to shrink the Windows partition, to create free space for Ubuntu. Not sure about Windows 8.